# methods in foreach and for loops in java

Tags: java, android

My question is regarding optimization in java using the Android compiler.  Will map.values() in the following be called every iteration, or will the Android compiler optimize it out.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map;

for (Object object : map.values())
{
   //do something with object
}
```

Likewise here is another example.  will aList.size() be called every iteration?

```
List<Object> aList;

for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
{
    object = aList.get(i);
    //do something with i
}
```

And after all this, does it really matter if it calls the methods every iteration?  Does Map.values(), and List.size() do much of anything?

Comment: This is a Java question that really has nothing to do with Android specifically.

Comment: I understand the interest in this question, but for any real-world purpose, I'd strongly suggest to profile code before optimizing it.

Comment: @PhilippReichart - It makes perfect sense to ask whether one coding style has an inherent performance advantage over another. Also, profiling has its limits. If you're coding for Android, your code is likely to run on a wide variety of platforms, some of which might have a JIT compiler, some of which will not, and some of which do not even exist yet.

Comment: @TedHopp I agree. I just want to caution people not to prematurely optimize, which usually is worse than loosing a cycle here or there.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the first example, `map.values()` will be evaluated once. According to the [Section 14.4.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), it is equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator<Object> i = map.values().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Object object = i.next();
    // do something with object
}
```

In the second, `aList.size()` will be called every time the test is evaluated. For readability, it would be better to code it as:

```
for (Object object : aList) {
    // do something with object
}
```

However, per the Android docs (on a page no longer available that I could find, but [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224091125/https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips)) this will be slower. Assuming that you aren't changing the list size inside the loop, <strike>the fastest</strike> another way would be to pull out the list size ahead of the loop:

```
final int size = aList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    object = aList.get(i);
    //do something with i
}
```

This will be substantially faster (the Android docs linked to above say by a factor of 3) if `aList` happens to be an `ArrayList`, but is likely to be slower (possibly by a lot) for a `LinkedList`. It all depends on exactly what kind of `List` implementation class `aList` is.

Comment: "Android docs" is a broken link. Here is the new one: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops. It adds a small correction to what Ted said about fastest loop - its not the fastest for devices without JIT ("foreach" is the fastest, and "foreach" is indistinguishable from "Ted's fastes loop" on devices with JIT).

Comment: @JustinCase - Thanks for tracking down the new location (and the new info). I've update the link in the answer itself.

Comment: The "new" link is broken... List.size() just gets a cached value. It's stupid to cache it again. I don't think any serious documentary has ever said otherwise, because it has never been otherwise.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan - I changed the link to an archived version at the Wayback Machine (archive.org). That will probably be a bit more stable . As to `List.size()` - yes, it retrieves a cached value, but caching it in a local variable eliminates a function call and allows other local optimizations.